# dynamodb decribe-table encryption status

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-dynamodb

In the AWS Console, the DynamoDB table is having Encryption as "DEFAULT"...looking at the documentation the table may be encrypted using AWS owned CMK(Customer managed key)...
But is there a way to know for sure...that the table is encrypted? and if yes, what type of encryption is in place?

the "describe-table" command doesn't output any information about encryption.

`C:\Users\test>aws dynamodb describe-table --profile snpp --table-name mydynamodbtable`

```
{
    "Table": {
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:902919223373:table/mydynamodbtable",
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "hashKey",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "rangeKey",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 100,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 400
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 45160931,
        "TableName": "mydynamodbtable",
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "TableId": "0e75b671-75bf-41ac-9cd1-f75ee3f787ca",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "KeyType": "HASH",
                "AttributeName": "hashKey"
            },
            {
                "KeyType": "RANGE",
                "AttributeName": "rangeKey"
            }
        ],
        "ItemCount": 206363,
        "CreationDateTime": 1529442343.583
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-dynamodb-encrypts-all-customer-data-at-rest/

Per this November 15, 2018 announcement, all DynamoDB table Data at rest are encrypted except for AWS GovCloud US-West, US-East, China Bejing, and China Ningxia  regions.